# Can We work with Ionic 2 and AngularJs 1?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I would like to develop applications using Ionic 2, but now I am working with angularJS1 with Ionic1.

I feel that AngularJs 1 is comfortable for me but not AngularJS 2, so is there any way to work with Ionic 2 and AngularJS 1?

Comment: I upvoted since it's an interesting question, but honestly, I would say it  makes no sense. And, I actually think it's not possible but someone please correct me if I'm wrong. Just invest the time to learn Angular 2 since it brings some good improvements and you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Thank u for your reply nikola i have asked this question because most of the ionic developers seeking the answer for this Question ... , If i am wrong sorry , but i hope this will bring some end point to this confusion ... @Nikola

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

> Ionic 2 is based on the new **2.x (and higher) version** of AngularJS, and comes with many significant performance, usability, and feature improvements.

Ionic (1) at a very high-level is essentially just a wrapper & directive/component library for AngularJS (1). In that same regard, Ionic 2 is built in the same way, utilizing all the benefits of Angular 2+.

So basically, everything must be upgraded in order to get the benefits of Ionic 2.  If everything you have is working, and performance isn't sluggish, there really is no reason to upgrade it, maybe if you were starting a new project (or the current project you have is small and it would be easy)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2 breaks away from being tied to the **DOM** in the browser, by using angular 2 which is the  reason for the massive change between ionic 1.x and ionic 2.x. ( Angular 2.x architecture is not  tied down to the DOM unlike the Angular 1.x ).

Although that means having to relearn and unlearn a lot of angular 1.x stuff, but this is a fundamental change that the ionic team has taken up in order to break away from the performance issues that has plagued ionic 1 and certainly well worth it. Now that the ionic 2 platform is stable well almost and certainly far better in **performance** to ionic 1, migrating is certainly a recommended option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular js 2 and Ionic 2 RC for your development.
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-mobile-app-with-angular-2-and-ionic-2
Scotch
Build a Mobile App with Angular 2 and Ionic 2
Update (September 30, 2016): Update article to recent ionic RC.0 releaseThis article has been updated to use Ionic 2 RC.0 ReleaseThe Ionic Framework... (33KB)

Since Ionic 2 RC will be forward compatible with Ionic 2 official release
Most of the time Enterprise will wait till an official release comes out

but RnD developers use RC packages also
you dnt have to worry..