# How do i create a ionic select box?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Am working on a ionic project and wanted to create an `ionic select box` which is as shown in this [documentation page](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#select)

Here is the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/suman_codepen/pen/xEWRag), where i have put sample of the example am working on.

```
<ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
            <ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple="true" cancelText="Nah" okText="Okay!">
              <ion-option value="bacon" checked="true">Bacon</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="olives">Black Olives</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="xcheese" checked="true">Extra Cheese</ion-option>
              <ion-option value="peppers">Green Peppers</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

Select box doesn't show-up instead all values of `<ion-option>` are appearing in same row.

How do i make sure it appears same as shown in documentation example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template you pasted and the documentation page you are pointing to is for Ionic2/Angular2 but you are using Ionic 1.3.1.

You can find the documentation for the select in Ionic 1.3 [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select)

Comment: Oops my bad ! BTW one more question out of curiosity, is there a way i can use Ionic2 with Angular1. I want these new look of Ionic 2. Am new to this new Ionic world so please bear with me !

Comment: This [SOF Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955053/can-we-work-with-ionic-2-and-angularjs-1) summed up everything. Thanks anyways :)