# How do I use JavaScript files in my ionic 2 project?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How do I use JavaScript files in my ionic 2 project?

Eg. 
I want to use terms like $scope in ionic 1 in ionic 2.
I want to write JavaScript code instead of Typescript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can We work with Ionic 2 and AngularJs 1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955053/can-we-work-with-ionic-2-and-angularjs-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Ionic 2 has made the transition to Angular, away from AngularJS.

If you want to continue to use AngularJS (and your familiarity with things such as `$scope`), you would have to stick with Ionic 1. Otherwise, learn Angular and move to Ionic 2.